# Give use to Android phone with broken screen

Tags: adb

I have an BLÜ Pure XR with a broken screen (completely black) which I'm trying to put to some use (security camera perhaps), however, since I can't access the phone at all, I'm not able to turn on USB Debugging, and all strategies I've found online (including putting the phone in ClockWork mode, which I seem to have done successfully) using ADB yield "Permission denied" errors in one form or another (`mount: Permission denied`, `adbd cannot run as root in production builds`, `...java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.os.IBinder android.os.IServiceManager.getService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference...`, etc).

I say I've successfully put the phone in ClockWork mode because if I connect it to my PC via USB and I run `adb devices` shows me a device in the list, and some of the errors I get include "BLÜ Pure XR" in their contents so it seems to be somewhat successfully connected.

Am I attempting to do something impossible?

Answer (score 0):

This will work only if the touch still works

1. Plug your phone to your pc
2. Unlock your phone
3. Perform the key combination which takes a screenshot
4. Explore the files of your phone where your screenshots are located
5. See where you are at
6. Tap on the screen blindli trying to click on the icon you want to click
7. Rinse and repeat from step 3

Comment: I can't do this, the screen is completely out, entirely black and doesn't recognize input.

Answer (score 0):

In case even your touch does not work, I believe the only way to do so is an iterative process using [UI Automator viewer](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-automator#ui-automator-viewer) and writing an UI Android test that navigates throughout the settings, enabling usb debugging as final goal.

UI Automator will be useful to collect the resource ids (menu items ids, textviews ids, dialog buttons ids, ui widgets ids etc) the instrumented test should click.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I will try this on the weekend and get back to you, thanks!